# R: create new dataframe rows are columns from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a simple one liner to create a new dataframe based on an original dataframe where the rownames (or at least first row) comes from the column names in the original dataframe?
for example:

```
Original <- data.frame("A"=c("apples", "aligator", "algebra"), "B"=c("Banana", "Beans", "Baby"))
```

Gives:

```
         A      B
1   apples Banana
2 aligator  Beans
3  algebra   Baby
```

What I want is:

```
A
B
```

Comment: you must be looking for transpose, try `t(Original)`. or if its just the column names then.. `colnames(original)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually figured it out - was very simple.

```
NewDataFrame <- data.frame(colnames(Original))
```